Applying a function to each data frame contained in a list
I have a list of data frames, and for each data frame in the list, I want to sum across the rows and store the result in a new column in that dataframe. So, I wrote this function:
timepoint_scores <- function(df_list) {
  for (i in 1:length(df_list)) {
    df <- df_list[[i]]
    df$total_score <- apply(df, 1, sum)
  } #end of for loop
}# end of timepoint_scores function

I know the df$total_score <- apply(df, 1, sum) works when I do this to an individual data frame, but I don't understand why this is not working as a for loop.

Because you are removing the dataframe from the list df <- df_list[[i]] but not putting it back in df_list. df is an individual object which is being overwritten in every iteration.
You may try :
timepoint_scores <- function(df_list) {
  for (i in 1:length(df_list)) {
    df_list[[i]]$total_score <- apply(df, 1, sum)
  } 
  return(df_list)
}

However, I would use lapply instead of for loop and rowSums instead of apply(df, 1, sum) which can be written as :
timepoint_scores <- function(df_list) {
  df_list <- lapply(df_list, \(x) {x$total_score <- rowSums(x);x})
  return(df_list)
}


How come my data frames do not update to show the added column in my global environment?
(I'm very new to R)

The line  df <- df_list[[i]]` is missing.
